# Not able to click UITextview email address

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to make an app that takes data from an sql database by getting a json encoded array.

It takes both address data and other types of data that is then passed on to a mapkit Map View element and some label/text view elements.

The Map View takes up about half the top half of the view. The bottom half of the view contains data about what is shown on the map.

The map works perfectly well and I can retrieve text for a label and textview in the bottom half of the app.

I am pulling an email address from the sql database and I want to show it in a Text View. The email is retrieved and inserted and it turns blue when I run the app but I still can't click it.

In the main.storyboard I have unchecked "Editable" and checked "selectable" and detection of "Links", "Addresses", "Phone Numbers", "Events" as well as checked "User Interaction Enabled".

Why is the email not clickable? I want to be able to click it so it will send an email.

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

import MapKit

class DetailViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var contactText: UITextView! 

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

var selectedLocation : LocationModel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let address = self.selectedLocation!.address

        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if placemarks?.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemarks?[0]
                let location = placemark?.location
                let coordinate = location?.coordinate

                     let viewRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate!, 1750, 1750)


                self.mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
                    // Plot pin
                let pin: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                pin.coordinate = coordinate!
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin)

                    //add title to the pin
                pin.title = self.selectedLocation!.overskrift

                if placemark?.areasOfInterest?.count > 0 {
                    //let areaOfInterest = placemark!.areasOfInterest![0]

                    //print(areaOfInterest)

                } else {
                    print("No area of interest found.")
                }
            }
        })


    textLabel.text = self.selectedLocation!.intro        

    //The following text should be a link but is not.
    contactText.text = self.selectedLocation!.email

} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tap gesture recognizer! Drag it on top of the connected text view, and connect it to your code with a function.